# spring mvc application on top of redis clustering

Tags: redis, spring-data, jedis

I am building a spring mvc-based web application by using redis for distributed cache for session management to provide high availability. I already set up redis cluster by following https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial and am able to make the application create session on one of the three redis instances.

Now I brought down the redis instance where the session data is stored to test the high availability, but I see bunch of following exception thrown which seems to be unable to connect to the redis instance which is down, but the web app crashes.

```
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:140)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:229)
```

I assume that redis promotes the slave (for the master which is down) to the master at this point.

But is there a way to make the app continue to work as expected by handling these connection errors in the application side?